# Comparing UIButtons that have UIImageViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uibutton, uiimage

I am writing a simple application that consists of 2 `UIImageViews` and 2 `UIButtons`. The `UIImageViews` are placed on top of the `UIButtons`.

I have 1 `UIImage` that appears on a random `UIImageView` and disappears after 2 seconds. The user then has to tap on the button they think the image appeared on.

I shuffle the `UIImageView` array and use the first element (index 0) for the image to be displayed on. When shuffling I keep track of which element (i.e from which index. lets say from index "n") was placed on index 0 of the array.

However, when a button is pressed i compare the id of the button pressed with the id of the button with index n. (because that is the index of the random `UIImageView`).
But for some reason it is not working. :(

Here is my code: (i didn't upload the .h file. it just contains declarations.)
The code below doesn't produce any error/warning messages. It just doesn't output the result I want.

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray* tempButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *tempViews;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *myImage;
@end

@implementation ViewController



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

     _myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"hello"];
    _tempButton = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:_button1, _button2, nil];

    _tempViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:_image1, _image2, nil];


     [self displayonView];

}



-(void)displayToFindSymbol{
    [_toFindImage setImage:_myImage];
    _toFindImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
}

- (IBAction)pressed:(id)sender {

    UIButton *result = (UIButton *)sender;
    if (result == _tempButton[_correctButton]) {
       NSLog (@"Correct");
    }
    else if (result != _tempButton[_correctButton]){
       NSLog (@"Incorrect");            

    }

}



-(NSMutableArray *)shuffleViews{
    NSUInteger count = _tempViews.count;
    int n;
    for (int i=count-1; i>=0; --i) {

        n = arc4random()  % (i + 1);


        [_tempViews exchangeObjectAtIndex:n withObjectAtIndex:i];
    }
    _correctButton = n;
    return _tempViews;

}

-(void)displayonView{

    NSMutableArray *tempArray;
    tempArray = [self shuffleViews]; // shuffle views

     _correctImage = [tempArray objectAtIndex:0];

    _correctImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

    [_correctImage setImage:_myImage];

    NSTimer* myTImer;
    myTImer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(hideLabel) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

}

-(void) hideLabel{
    _correctImage.hidden = YES;
    for (UIButton *each in self.tempButton) {
        each.enabled = YES;
    }
    [self displayToFindSymbol];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use tags instead, set a unique tag to both of the buttons, and set the tag of image to the button that the image will belong, later on, compare the tag of both image and the button to check if they are the same or not.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/tag

Answer (score 0):

I'm kinda new to objective-c and iOS aswell, but i don't think you should compare like this:

```
result == _tempButton[_correctButton]
```

try this comparison instead:

```
[result isEqual:_tempButton[_correctButton]]
```